# Encrypt/Decrypt an animated gif in Python without storing the final copy to HD

Tags: python, encryption, pycrypto, in-memory

Okay, let's try this again.

I'm trying to encrypt an animated gif with PyCrypto to be sent to someone. After the receiver gets it, they should be able to run my pycrypto script and view the animated image- WITHOUT storing the unencrypted file to the hard drive. Essentially I'm trying to save the unencrypted file in-memory so that it can be accessed by another library without saving it to the disk.

For encryption I've been using

```
import os, random, struct
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def encrypt_file(key='8c57d066796428d5a8f4b012155dad90', in_filename='tile.png', out_filename=None, chunksize=8192):
    """ Encrypts a file using AES (CBC mode) with the
        given key.

        key:
            The encryption key - a string that must be
            either 16, 24 or 32 bytes long. Longer keys
            are more secure.

        in_filename:
            Name of the input file

        out_filename:
            If None, '<in_filename>.enc' will be used.

        chunksize:
            Sets the size of the chunk which the function
            uses to read and encrypt the file. Larger chunk
            sizes can be faster for some files and machines.
            chunksize must be divisible by 16.
    """
    if not out_filename:
        out_filename = in_filename + '.enc'

    iv = ''.join(chr(random.randint(0, 0xFF)) for i in range(16))
    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    filesize = os.path.getsize(in_filename)

    with open(in_filename, 'r') as infile:
        with open(out_filename, 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(struct.pack('<Q', filesize))
            outfile.write(iv)

            while True:
                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break
                elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
                    chunk += ' ' * (16 - len(chunk) % 16)

                outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))
```

, but that doesn't seem to be doing anything at all. I don't even know where to begin on the decryption part because again, I need to be able to access the decrypted file without storing it to the hard drive.

Thanks guys.

Comment: :) Looks much better.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if I came across as noobish or rude earlier. Been racking my head for hours trying to figure this out and it's driving me up the wall.

Comment: It's perfectly fine. We want to help, and we can't when you don't make it explicit what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) instead of an actual disc file called `out_filename`?

Just use a virtual disc with the same structure.

Example:

```
import StringIO

f=StringIO.StringIO()

for line in ['line {}\n'.format(i) for i in range(25)]:
    f.write(line)

f.seek(0)

for line in f:
    print line.strip()
```

So you would need to replace `with open(out_filename, 'w') as outfile: ...` with a call to `outfile=StringIO.StringIO()` and the rest should be the same.

Like so:

```
with open(in_filename, 'r') as infile:
    outfile=StringIO.StringIO()
    outfile.write(struct.pack('<Q', filesize))
    outfile.write(iv)

    while True:
        chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
        if len(chunk) == 0:
            break
        elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
            chunk += ' ' * (16 - len(chunk) % 16)

        outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))
```

Comment: This looks like what I need, but are StringIO objects treated exactly like files? Example being if I were to use stringIO to store the decrypted gif file, could it be accessed with PIL as if it were an actual image?

Comment: Yes. You can operate on StringIO files with PIL

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I'm looking for- What took me hours to figure out you guys did in minutes. Should've turned to SO in the first place. Thanks guys!

Comment: Forgot to add: the caveat of StringIO objects is that you can often forget there is (for lack of remembering what the correct phrase is) a cursor position on the `file`.  Depending on how you write things, after you've written the file, you'll probably need to `obj.seek(0)` to reset the position for reading.  You'd need to do this on a normal file if you didn't close it too, but most people open/write/close open/read as separate actions.